# Copying a generic protobuf into a new object on the heap

Tags: c++, c++11, protocol-buffers, deep-copy

I want to make a copy of a generic `const` protobuf [`Message`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message) for further manipulation. I came up with

```
Message* myfn(const Message *msg) {
  Message *copy = msg->New();
  copy->CopyFrom(*msg);
  // do stuff
  return copy;
}
```

Is this correct/idiomatic? Or is there a better way (perhaps C++11 specific)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct.

If you want type safety a little template magic can help:

```
template<class Msg, 
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<protobuf::Message,
                                          Msg>::value>>
std::unique_ptr<Msg> clone(const Msg* msg)
{
  std::unique_ptr<Msg> p(msg->New());
  p->CopyFrom(*msg);
  return p;
}
```

And you'll see that I have wrapped the protocol buffers object in a unique_ptr. This provides some exception safety and has the added advantage of being convertible to shared_ptr.

Why is this a good idea? Well, consider a protocol buffer object called Foo that has 2 string members called bar and baz:

```
void test(const Foo* source_foo)
{
  // clone and convert the unique_ptr to shared_ptr
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> myclone(clone(source_foo));

  myclone->bar() += " cloned";
  myclone->baz() += " cloned again";

  // get a shared_ptr to the members:
  auto mybar = std::shared_ptr<const std::string>(myclone, &myclone->bar());
  auto mybaz = std::shared_ptr<const std::string>(myclone, &myclone->baz());

  give_away(mybar);
  do_something_else(mybaz);

  // at this point the use_count of myclone is at least 3. 
  // if give_away results in holding on to the shared_ptr 
  // to string then myclone will be kept 
  // alive until the last shared_ptr goes away 

}
```

Comment: Could this be outdated? I can't use the function like that.. `std::shared_ptr<ProtoTestMsg> myclone( clone( testMsg ) ):` gives me `error: no matching function for call to ‘clone(ProtoTestMsg*&)’
    std::shared_ptr<ProtoTestMsg> myclone( clone( testMsg ) );`

Comment: @madmax The documentation still lists the CopyFrom method: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.CopyFrom.details
 but it is possible that things have moved on.

Comment: My problem is not the CopyFrom method, but the clone method. (I call it cloneMsg) ->  `error: no matching function for call to ‘cloneMsg(ProtoTestMsg*&)’
    std::unique_ptr<ProtoTestMsg> myclone(static_cast<ProtoTestMsg*>(cloneMsg( testMsg )));`

Comment: @madmax difficult to comment without seeing your code. I know that's not easy since it involves the step of compiling proto files

Comment: @RichardHodges I am getting the same compiler error as @madmax. I dabbled with this for at least an hour and couldn't figure out how to correctly call `clone()`. Could this be an issue with C++ language version or such? `.proto` files are already successfully built BTW.